# Update and show pictures in a loop with PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a simple script that periodically takes a screenshot of my screen and saves it on a shared folder. I am now looking to build a script that takes this screenshot and displays it on another PC, updating the displayed picture when the other script runs. I have found this code online which works fine and displays the first pic it finds at the location:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'My Screen'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('D:\\screen.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(),pixmap.height())
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried to modify it like this to make it update every 60 seconds:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'My Screen'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()
        while True:
            self.update_image()
            time.sleep(60)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('D:\\screen.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(),pixmap.height())
        self.show()

    def update_image(self):
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('D:\\screen.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(),pixmap.height())
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But it's obviously a stupid solution and it doesn't work. Do any of you have an idea of how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: you need to use non-blocking delays (ie `time.sleep` is a BLOCKING delay) (I think in QT that would be something like `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.call_me_after_2_seconds)`)

Comment: Thank you! So simple I can't believe I didn't think about it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments you must use a `QTimer`, on the other hand you want to upload a file with the same name so in that case it is better to reuse the `QLabel` because otherwise your application will consume a lot of memory.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

path_of_image = 'D:\\screen.png'

class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'My Screen'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update_image)
        timer.start(60*1000)
        self.update_image()

    def update_image(self):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(path_of_image)
        if not pixmap.isNull():
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.label.adjustSize()
            self.resize(pixmap.size())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple I can't believe I didn't think about it ;)